# Cannot add cpp-httplib library to c++ cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake

I have just started a c++ CMAKE project (I am pretty new to this) and I wanted to add the library [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/). I cloned the repository in my project. My CMAKE looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("OrderOptimizer")
add_executable (OrderOptimizer "OrderOptimizer.cpp" "OrderOptimizer.h")
add_subdirectory("cpp-httplib")
target_link_libraries(OrderOptimizer PRIVATE cpp-httplib)
```

My project folder structure looks like this:

```
OrderOptimizer/
     cpp-httplib/
     CmakeLists.txt
     OrderOptimizer.cpp
     OrderOptimizer.h
```

In my executable OrderOptimizer.cpp I have this code:

```
#include "OrderOptimizer.h"
#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT
#include "httplib.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    httplib::Server svr;

    svr.Get("/hi", [](const httplib::Request&, httplib::Response& res) {
        res.set_content("Hello World!", "text/plain");
        });

    svr.listen("0.0.0.0", 8080);

    return 0;
}
```

In the error box it shows me 600 erros. I am developing this on a windows 11 machine in Visual Studio 2022. I guess I am missing something, but for the life of me cannot figure out.

How to fix this? What am I missing? In general I am just starting to learn about CMAKE and c++ so I don't have much experience with this.

I tried different CMAKE configurations but without success. I also tried different libraries/repositories for REST API's but without success. Any help to guide me how to add external libraries to such a project would be helpfull.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A735Y4kMIPM) tutorial, but without success of my own.

Comment: what are the errors? Start with the first

Comment: E0035 Sorry, OpenSSL versions prior to 1.1.1 are not supported. E0258 'this' may only be used in a nonstatic method (30 of this type of error). Cannot open source file openssl/err.h .... There are too many for me to fix since this is code that should run out of the box.

Comment: "There are too many for me to fix since this is code that should run out of the box." - Still, you need to fix these errors one by one. Start with the very **first** one and try to fix it. After fixing repeat the building and obtain new list of errors. It is very possible that some of the previous errors are automatically fixed with the first one. When fixing an error, make sure to search for it. If you cannot fix a particular error, and search doesn't help, then ask about that **specific error**. When asking, make sure to include to the question post the **complete error message**.

Comment: @otiv33 put the first few errors in the question, please

Comment: Suggest start building a simple program _without_ including your OrderOptimizer.h, and _without_ `CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT`. Add more complexity once you have hello world working. Note open ssl requires more dependencies, which it doesn't look like you've provided.

Comment: Alright. I removed the ```#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT``` and now I only have 1 error which is progress. The error: LNK1104 cannot open file 'cpp-httplib.lib'. Any ideas?

Comment: @otiv33 I put together an answer which gets something simple working. It's hard to know why you're getting the link error without more information, but in any case I don't think manually bringing in cpp-httlib is the right way to go -- better to use fetch content or a package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest thing is to use [fetch content](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) to get the dependency.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26) # 3.26 comes with Visual Studio 2022
include(FetchContent)

project(OrderOptimizer)

FetchContent_Declare(httplib SYSTEM
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib
    GIT_TAG a609330e4c6374f741d3b369269f7848255e1954 # v0.14.1
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(httplib)

add_executable(OrderOptimizer OrderOptimizer.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OrderOptimizer PRIVATE httplib)
```

This builds, after your comment

> Alright. I removed the #define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT and now I only have 1 error which is progress. The error: LNK1104 cannot open file 'cpp-httplib.lib'. Any ideas?

However, whilst using fetch content is better than trying to install the dependency yourself, I'd advise using a package manager like [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/) (using a vcpkg.json in your project), or [conan](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/#ssl-support). With that approach you'd also be able to bring in the required ssl etc (dependencies listed [here](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/#ssl-support)).

For vcpkg, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg. To install it, see https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started. It can be convenient to install it alongside your other projects:

```
dev 
  OrderOptimizer
  vcpkg
```

in which case you can tell CMake to use vcpkg by pointing it at the toolchain file in `OrderOptimizer/../vcpkg...`. CMakeLists.txt becomes

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26) # 3.26 comes with Visual Studio 2022

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
    CACHE FILEPATH "vcpkg toolchain file location")
project(OrderOptimizer)

find_package(httplib CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(OrderOptimizer OrderOptimizer.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OrderOptimizer PRIVATE httplib)
```

and you need a vcpkg file, at least

```
{
    "dependencies": [
        "cpp-httplib"
    ]
}
```

Note there is a *lot* more to setting up a project than this -- I have barely scratched the surface, so do read up on the details. E.g, in CMake you can use presets, and in vcpkg you can ["parameterise" a dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/examples/selecting-llvm-features) to select a feature.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. With this I managed to get it working, thank you. If I try to go the vcpkg route I install vcpkg and install the package and I add ```find_package(cpp-httplib REQUIRED)``` and ```target_link_libraries(OrderOptimizer PRIVATE cpp-httplib)``` into my CMAKE file?

Comment: @otiv33 I added vcpkg details. If you follow their install instructions, it should be quite straightforward to get something working. But, again, it's just a the bare bones.